# Iphone string variable difficulty

Tags: objective-c, string, ios4

This is my code below and I want to make the value in the XML string being read from my valueVariable but not static 0. how can I do that. I heard about stringWithFormat: but I couodnt apply it since my string is in a replacement function. My real string is much longer and messy.

```
NsInteger valueVariable=0;
theXML =[theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<valuedefinition/>" withString:@"<variablevalue value=\"0\"/><source type>"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Snippet:**

```
NSInteger integer = 0;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<variablevalue value=\"%d\"/>",integer];
```

**Output:**

```
<variablevalue value="0"/>
```

**Note:**

It's strongly recommended to use libraries like [KissXML](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/) to create, edit and parse XML-files.

Comment: How can I use a library for purpose like this? I already use gdataxml for parsing